# Why does m[1] - m[0] return 3 where m is a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

This is my code:

```
int m[][3] = {
               { 0 , 1 , 2  },
               { 10, 11, 12 },
               { 20, 21, 22 }
             };
printf("%d %d\n", m[1] - m[0], m[1][0] - m[0][0]);
```

And why does

```
m[1] - m[0]
```

return `3`? I know why the second expression would return `10` but the 1<sup>st</sup> one doesn't seem logical to me.

Comment: `m[1]` is `&m[1][0]` and so on.

Comment: Technically, `m` is not a 3x3 matrix but an array of arrays.

Comment: No answers mentioned this yet, but `m[0]` and `m[1]` are *arrays* (not pointers). A pointer value is produced when the array is used as operand of the `-` operator, which points to the first element of the respective array.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In your code:

```
 m[1] - m[0]
```

denotes a pointer subtraction which gives you the difference of the two pointers based on the *type*. In this case, both the pointers are differentiated by 3 elements, so the result is 3.

To quote `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.6

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements. [...]

and

> [...] In other words, if the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, the `i`-th and `j`-th elements of
>   an array object, the expression `(P)-(Q)` has the value `i−j` provided the value fits in an object of type `ptrdiff_t`. [....]

To help visualize better, please see the following image

[image]

Here, `s` is a two dimensional array, defined as `s[4][2]`. Considering the data type of the array consumers 2 byte each, please follow the elements (index) and corresponding memory location (*arbitrary*). This will give a better understating how actually in memory, the array elements are contiguous.

So, as per the representation, `s[0]` and `s[1]` are differentiated by two elements, `s[0][0]` and `s[0][1]`. Hence, `s[1] - s[0]` will produce a result of 2.

Comment: Thankyou! This helped me understand it. I will definetly pass that test now :)

Comment: @Martacus That's the confidence !! Best of luck :)

Comment: Note that `m[1]` and `m[0]` are arrays.  The pointers you describe are the result of "decay".

Answer (score 36):

Because the "difference" between `m[1]` and `m[0]` is three elements.

It might be easier to understand if you look at it like this

```
m[0]                          m[1]                          m[2]
|                             |                             |
v                             v                             v
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| m[0][0] | m[0][1] | m[0][2] | m[1][0] | m[1][1] | m[1][2] | m[2][0] | m[2][1] | m[2][2] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The difference between `m[1]` and `m[0]` is the *three* elements `m[0][0]`, `m[0][1]` and `m[0][2]`.

Comment: Ah yes, this explains it further too, thanks! I got the hang of it now haha.

Comment: Actually, the `m[0]` will technically point to the same location as `m[0][0]` if you look at it in technical terms. Using `&m[0]` and `&m[0][0]` will prove that; arrays have a base and an offset, and so both `m[0]` and `m[0][0]` have zero offset and an address equal to the matix's base address.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you should point `m[0]` to the middle of the cell containing `m[0][0]`, not the start. Same goes for `m[1]` and `m[2]`.